# Does mongoose expires 'restarts' after we alter the document other values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose i have a Schema as follows:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 3600 }
});

const User= mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const user = new User({name: 'Me'});

console.log(user);

setTimeout(function () {
    User.update({name: 'Me'}, {name: 'You'}).exec((err, user) => console.log(user));
    //update statement is incorrect, but i think you got my point
}, 2000);
```

So i wanted to know if updating the document will reset the document's expire time if other if change the `name` attribute, or the time will restart (reset) only if the `createdAt` value is change.

The Mongoose documentation does not have any point on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, modifying a document's fields other than `createdAt` has no effect on when the document expires.

The document will expire when: `current time >= createdAt + 3600`